java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to create JSON file in Google Drive Appfolder
I’m writing an Android App where I need to save some data in Google Drive Appfolder.
I have configured my app on Google Cloud Console:

Configure Consent screen (I have configured the Scopes)
Create OAuth client ID credentials (for Android and Web application)
Enable Google Drive API

In my Android application, I have managed Authentication and then Authorization (with AuthorizationClient API). Both are successful.
I’m then using the following code to create a dummy json file in Appfolder:
// Source: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata
private void saveToDriveAppFolder(AuthorizationResult authorizationResult) {
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(new AccessToken(authorizationResult.getAccessToken(), null));

    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(
            new NetHttpTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials))
            .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .build();
    try {
        // File's metadata.
        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName("config.json");
        fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
        java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/config.json");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);
        File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
        Log.w(TAG,"File ID: " + file.getId());

    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

but I’m getting this exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: files/config.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Would you know why or what I should check?
Thank you!

can't test this.. BUT
sometime, a directory needs to be created before a file can be written in it...
and since you don't mention that the "files" folder exists.... couldn't it be the issue here ?
Just a hunch....

Laurent, 2 days ago I have thought to this possibility and commented "files/" to get the JSON file created at the root but I had the same problem.
